# Want to copy files from HDFS to local machine

Tags: bigdata

Trying to copy files from `hdfs` to local machine using `copyToLocal` with the following command:

```
Hadoop fs -copyToLocal remote path(hdfs file) destinationPath (my local path)
```

But I am getting the following error:

> No such file or directory: error

Please help me with this.

Comment: As per the error it clearly show that  source hdfs path is not available. Check it .

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the data from hdfs to the local filesystem by following two ways:

bin/hadoop fs -get /hdfs/source/path /localfs/destination/path

bin/hadoop fs -copyToLocal /hdfs/source/path /localfs/destination/path

Another alternative way would be:
Download the file from hdfs to the local filesystem. Just, point your web browser to HDFS WEBUI(namenode_machine:50070) and select the file and download it.